# Key-based query in Cloud NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I’m guessing this is very simple, but I’m having a hard time getting it right. I successfully created multiple Entities of the type

```
class Word(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    definition = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Now I want to query for a specific Entity in the most efficient way possible. So I am doing

```
with client.context():
  ans = Word.query(ndb.Key(“Word”,”love”)).get()
```

But I get an error

```
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ndb/query.py", line 1531, in filter
    "Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received %r" % filter
TypeError: Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received Key(‘Word’, ‘love’)”
```

I look in my datastore and the word is there. How do I do this successfully?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out all I had to do was

```
with client.context():
  ans = ndb.Key(“Word”,”love”).get()
```